# Are all glitches from the original games still present on the NES Classic Mini?

Tags: nes, nes-classic-mini

Some of the games that are reissued on the NES Classic Mini have well-known and well documented glitches, such as jumping through a wall in *Super Mario Bros.*.

These glitches are exploited to save time in speed runs.

**Are these glitches still present in the versions of these games that are included on the NES Classic Mini?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Most are, but not all.**

The answer is definitely yes in the case of a glitch like wall clipping in Super Mario Bros. A simple glitch like that is an unintended result of ordinary gameplay code which, unless specifically altered, will be faithfully reproduced by the emulator.

There are so far no know examples of Nintendo fixing glitches like this (intentionally or unintentionally) in any of their Virtual Console or Classic/Mini console emulators. Things that have been changed in the emulated re-releases include consistency fixes for regional version differences, reductions in bright flashing colors to reduce the risk of seizures, and occasional minor graphical cleanup ([examples](https://tcrf.net/Super_Mario_RPG:_Legend_of_the_Seven_Stars#Virtual_Console_Changes)).

Where an emulator might not faithfully reproduce a glitch is where it involves the low-level hardware. Many NES and SNES games have glitches/crashes which behave a certain way because of the memory and processor systems specific to the console. Emulated re-releases may exhibit different behavior when such a glitch is triggered, may crash where the original hardware didn't (or vice versa), or may be unaffected by the glitch altogether.

Comment: Great answer. I guess I'll ask a follow-up question if I want to know about a specific glitch.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely yes.

The main reason is they gain nothing fixing them, and they're extremely hard to fix.

You can expect all the development hardware and software are over 30 years old.

Just because they have a ROM, it doesn't mean they can fix it.  Fixing bugs of this type via ROM hacking is non-trivial.

Comment: I was thinking about accidental fixes, mostly. I agree that intentional fixes are unlikely.

Comment: They wouldn't touch it at all.  I bet they won't even have updated copyright.

Comment: They don't have to have updated copyright information since it's in the console documentation.  That, and Nintendo contracts from back in the day were half-exclusivity and perpetuity contracts.  Plus, some of the associated companies no longer exist and their IP rights are probably in the ether.

Comment: I'm not worried about the actual legal copyright.  I'm just talking about that tiny number in most software I see that accompanies the copyright logo.  Anyways, they would update nothing because even the tiniest change is massively complex.